# What is the difference between v[0], v.begin() and v.data() of a vector v?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I need to display my vector which was sorted using merge sort algorithm. However, my friend used v.data() to pass the vector while I used v.begin().
His code is working perfectly whilst mine doesn't. Please explain.

I have already tried passing v[0] and v.begin(). It doesn't work.

```
void merge_sort(int *a, int i, int j);

void merge_sort(int *a, int i, int j) 
{
    int mid;

    if (i < j) {
        mid = (i + j) / 2;

        merge_sort(a, i, mid);       // left recursion

        merge_sort(a, mid + 1, j);   // right recursion

        merge(a, i, mid, mid + 1, j); 
    }
}

int main() 
{

    int num;
    cout << "Enter array length (n) = ";
    cin >> num;

    vector<int> a(num);

    cout << "Enter the number:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    merge_sort(a.data(), 0, num - 1);

    cout << "\nSorted array :\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

v.begin() and v[0] shows errors whilst v.data() works perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Farhan! :) Where is the definition for your `merge()` method?

Comment: `v[0]` is not valid (out of bounds) if the container is empty. For `v.begin()`, that in itself is valid, but *dereferencing* the iterator is invalid if the container is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume a vector `v` of type `std::vector<int>`. Then:

- `v[0]` returns a **reference** to the first vector element and `v` must not be empty (otherwise, the behavior is not defined). The type of this expression is `int&` or `const int&`.
- `v.data()` returns a **pointer** to the first vector element, or some unspecified pointer value if `v` is empty. The type of this expression is `int*` or `const int*`.
- `v.begin()` returns an **iterator** to the first vector element, or `v.end()` if `v` is empty. The type of this expression is `std::vector<int>::iterator` or `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`.

Since your `merge_sort` expects, as its first argument, a pointer (`int* a`), then, out of those three expressions, only `v.data()` has a suitable type. Or course, you can also pass `&v[0]` as well as `&*v.begin()`.

Comment: it can be empty for `v.data()`

Comment: While you may answer the title of the question, I don't know if you actually help the OP (a new contributor too), I mean if i was the OP some years ago, I am not sure if I was going to get everything from this answer.. EDIT: Yes now your answer has improved, bravo! :)

Comment: I think `v[0]` also has undefined behaviour when v is empty because it is not required to check the bounds.

Comment: @churill Yes, [it has](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#tab:container.seq.opt).

Answer (score 1):

`v.data()` : Returns a direct pointer to the memory array used internally by the vector to store its owned elements

`v[0]` : first element of the vetcor

`v.begin()` : return iterator to first element of vector

Your function `void merge_sort(int *a, int i, int j);` take pointer..
so `v.data()` works fine..